# Не срабатывает number_format (PHP)

Tags: php

Пытаюсь привести число в нужный формат работая с переменной другой переменной:

```
$number_format = ${$data_1}[0];
echo number_format($number_format, 0, ',', ' ');
```

Не выводит никаких данных.

Вот такой вариант выводит лишь

```
echo number_format(${$data_1}[0], 0, ',', ' ');
```

> 0

В чем ошибка?

Просто:

```
echo ${$data_1}[0];
```

Работает.

**Результаты var_dump:**

```
var_dump(${$data_1}[0])
```

> :object(SimpleXMLElement)[1422]  public 0 => string '16340874.00'
>   (length=11)

```
var_dump(number_format(${$data_1}[0], 0, ',', ' '));
```

> :null

Comment: а в чем собственно ошибка заключается? формат не тот, значение не то? покажите `$data_1` как у вас определена

Comment: Что выводит вот этот ваш код?

Comment: Ничего не выводит. Ни ошибки  и никаких данных. Перепробовал разные комбинации уже и ничего.

Comment: так что у вас там в $$data_1?

Comment: Число типа: 11014252.00

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод команды `var_dump(${data_1})`

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, вам нужно проверить `var_dump($data_1)` и `var_dump(number_format($number_format, 0, ',', ' '))`
Скорее всего, ошибка во входящих данных, то есть `$data_1` или  `$number_format` пустые. Так же можете попробовать упростить формат.

Comment: Действительно, проверил - null. Но почему я получаю переменную без форматирования? Вот так: echo ${$data_1}[0];

Answer (score 1):

После комментариев стало все ясно, а зачем вы используете конструкцию `${$data_1}[0]`? а не просто `${$data_1}`, так как ваша переменная не строковая, то `[0]` ничего не возвращает, а `number_format` возвращает `0`

Comment: А как мне тогда получить первый элемент массива в этом случае?

Comment: какого массива, если вы говорите, что `$$data_1 = 11014252.00`? Если у вас должен массив, то `$$data_1` должен иметь вид `$$data_1 = [11014252.00, 12014252.00, 13014252.00]`, или я вас не правильно понимаю?

Comment: если так, то проверьте, справа от `$$data_1` все ли верно отдается

Comment: Он имеет ввиду, что это может быть число, вам нужно проверить тип gettype ( )

Comment: Просто данные echo ${$data_1}[0]; отдаются. Получаю число. Но как мне его в нужный формат привести? Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @Frontendman за вас `php` все сам переводит, но получается вы ему все таки не то отдаете. Выведите в две строки подряд: `var_dump(${$data_1}[0]);` и `var_dump(number_format(${$data_1}[0], 0, ',', ' '));` и напишите, что у вас отобразилось. Главное, чтобы они друг за другом были, вдруг у вас в коде еще что-то есть

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: @Frontendman, так `${$data_1}[0]` у вас объект `SimpleXMLElement`, поэтому не работает

Comment: вы передаете объект, а нужно значение из этого объекта

Comment: Т.е. дело в массиве и неправильном обращении  к нему?

Comment: да, у вас получается массив из объектов

Comment: если не много не понятно, вот как пример, куда копать, посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object